# Problem with raster package in R: object '_raster_availableRAM' not found

Tags: r

I have a problem with the raster package. It does not allow me to work with raster layers. For example, with this code:

```
mapa_base_crop <- crop(mapa_base, extent(460000,700000,4610000,4860000))
```

> Error in .availableRAM(maxmem) : object '_raster_availableRAM' not
>   found

Comment: Something must have gone wrong with the installation.  Re-install Rcpp and raster. If that does not solve the problem. What versions do you have, etc? (show `sessionInfo()`

Comment: Thank you very much. It already works well. I had reinstalled the "raster" package but not the "Rcpp" package.